# Should the license header be preceded by the copyright holder?

Tags: copyright, license

I'm open sourcing a proprietary codebase (license TBD, probably Apache) were all files have the header:

```
Copyright <company name>. All rights reserved.
```

Should this line be preserved in addition to the license header, or replaced by it?

I'm planning to use a DCO rather than CLA for external contributions (if that makes any difference).

Comment: With that (or any) license, the 'all rights reserved' is a bit superfluous or even contradictory

Answer (score 3):

It is good to have a copyright notice next to the license notice in your files. That give the users of your code some indication who the rights holders are.

A properly formatted copyright notice has the format

```
Copyright <year> <rights holder>
```

where the year is a list or range of years in which (copyright-significant) changes to the file were published and `rights holder` is the name of the person or legal entity that owns the copyrights on those changes.

If there are multiple contributors at different times, then you can have a separate copyright notice for each of them. If there are really many contributors, people tend to combine the list or rights holders in a smaller number of copyright notices.

The "All rights reserved" indication you have I would recommend to drop, as it is contradictory to the license indication that follows and can cause confusion.